# What is differences between RDD and a traditional Relational Database System

Tags: apache-spark, relational-database, rdd, rdbms

I am new to spark, I know SQL but would like to know the differences between RDD(Resilient Distributed Datasets) and Relational databases like in architecture level and access level. Thank you.

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#resilient-distributed-datasets-rdds  ... check this out.

Comment: RDD is a collection of records, not **relational** entities. If you want to map your thinking to database tables you should rather be looking at `Dataset` objects. You *access* an RDD like a `ResultSet` in JDBC , e.g. `getColumn(x)`... Not sure this answers your question

Answer (score 1):

RDD(Resilient Distributed Dataset) is a in memory data structure used by Spark. It is immutable data structure. Think of it as , spark has loaded data in memory in a specific structure and that structure is called RDD. Once your spark job stops, there is no RDD existence.

Database on other hand are storage systems. You can store your data and query that later.

I hope this clarify. One more thing - Spark can load data from a file system or database and create a RDD. filesystem and database are two places where data is stored. Once that data is loaded in memory by spark. spark uses a data structure named RDD to store and process it.